# Is there an advantage in how I store my data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know understand more about how jQuery stores data.

Is there any advantage to doing one or the other of these:

```
$('#editCity').data('href', "xx");
var a = $('#editCity').data('href');
```

or

```
$('#editCity').attr('data-href', "xx");
var a = $('#editCity').attr('data-href');
```

One more related question.

If I have this:

```
var modal = { x: 'xx', y: 'yy' };
```

Can I also store this using .data( .. ) ?

Comment: `.data()` is de facto here. While browsers could also store objects and references inside `data-*` attribute, `.data()` will guarantee higher compatibility, I haven't tested though, but I'd say - close to 100%.

Comment: It's also respects the dataset spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing property values directly on DOM elements is risky because of possible memory leaks. If you're using jQuery anyway, the `.data()` mechanism is a wonderful and safe way to keep track of per-element information. It allows for storage of arbitrary JavaScript data structures too, not just strings.

*edit* — when your HTML markup contains `data-foo` attributes, those are implicitly read when the keys are accessed.  That is, if your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="div1" data-purpose="container">
```

Then in jQuery:

```
alert( $('#div1').data('purpose') ); // alerts "container"
```

Furthermore, jQuery will also do some "smart" analysis of the attribute values.  If a value looks like a number, jQuery will return a number, not a string. If it looks like JSON, it de-serializes the JSON for you.

*edit* — here's a good trick: in the Chrome developer console (the "Console" view), you can type JavaScript expressions and have them evaluated. The evaluation is always done in the context of the page you're working on.  If you select an element from the "Elements" view, then in the console the JavaScript symbol `$0` will refer to that selected DOM element.  Thus you can always inspect the "data" map for an element by going to the console and typing something like:

```
$($0).data("something");
```

The `.data()` function, if called with no parameters, returns *all* the key/value pairs:

```
$($0).data();
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the possible memory leaks?

Comment: I keep changing my site from one to another :-) Just changed back to .attr('data-.  However I can change back again. Sounds like you recommend .data. Can you explain more about memory leaks?

Comment: Am I still able to use Chrome Debug or another debugger to find the values that I set if I use .data() ?

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting point about the data function is that you can add any kind of object, for example your `modal`. And jQuery, as stated in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), take care of avoiding memory leaks when the DOM changes :

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   free from memory leaks.

For strings, memory leaks aren't possible but the main difference is that the first solution is cleaner (more coherent if you might store other data than strings in other parts of your application), clearer (the intent is evident), and doesn't force CSS calculation (DOM isn't changed).

Comment: Can I find out what's been set when using a debugger such as firefox or Chrome developer tools if .data() is used?

Comment: You can always execute in the console `$(yourSelector).data('yourkey')`.

Comment: Am I right in saying one advantage is that when writing HTML I can specify data-href in the HTML. My web pages are created dynamically and this helps me.

Comment: @Anne when you add `data-something` attributes, the `.data()` mechanism will *read* the initial value for a key from the element.  In other words, if you have not yet called `x.data("key", "something");` then calling `var value = x.data("key")` will access the `data-key` attribute on your element. It will not ever *update* the attribute value, however.

Answer (score 0):

They both have advantages... That said, 99% of the time you should be using `.data('whatever', value)`

Advantages of using `.data('whatever', value)`:

- less apt to cause memory leaks because it's not using the DOM.
- Slightly faster to pull data from memory than from the DOM.
- Can put any type of object in it without serializing it to JSON first.

Advantages of using `.attr('data-whatever', value)`:

- compatible with `.data('whatever')`
- allows you to select the element by the value: `$('[data-whatever=foo]')`
- You can put any object in it, but it will need to serialize if it's a complex type.

Comment: Is not another advantage of using .attr that I can easily set the data when writing to the HTML and when viewing with a debugger?

Comment: @Anne viewing with debugger is easy with the console, `$(element).data()`. Another advantage of `.attr('data-whatever')` is it allows you to get the string value regardless of what it is. For example, if you were storing zip codes, you would want to use `.attr()` rather than `.data()` because `.data()` may do rounding or drop zeros.